# MUI TextField(multiline) having a helper text and characters remaining limit

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textarea

I am trying to make a **textarea** component with MUI and I have got the following designs -

[Design - 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UC0Yi.png)

[Desgin - 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMS91.png)

I don't think they can be achieved in any way with the **TextAreaAutosize** of MUI -
https://mui.com/base/api/textarea-autosize/

I have seen **MUI Textfield multiline** prop maybe I can use that because I will have a **helperText** to at least achieve something from the design like in the **codesandbox** -

https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-butterfly-dl1xil?file=/demo.tsx

Will it be the right solution???

Comment: Did you try [multiline prop](https://mui.com/base/react-input/#multiline)?